# Python function input with variable length

Tags: string, function, variables, python-2.7

This is kind of vague, but I'm in the process of making an english-to-kong translator.  Kong, being the "language" where a word like "grape" turns into "gong rong a pong e", requires that I split the input word, in this case grape, into each individual letter, check if it's a vowel, and if not append "ong" to it.

I came across the problem that the only way I could do this was if I knew the number of letters in the word, because I ended up running each letter through a function that checked if it was a vowel, and if not appended "ong".  To do that, I did `first = word[0]`, `second = word[1]`, and so on, and ran those through the `vowelchecker` function.

Is there some way that I could have any word with any number of letters go through the function and still come out properly?

Comment: You should use a list here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through a string as a list of letters.

For example:

```
word = 'grape'
for a in word:
    #do something
```

Here, in each iteration of the loop, `a` will be set to the value of the current letter of the `word` string. You don't need to know the length ahead of time because the loop will run until it has looped through all the letters (unless you write a condition to break the loop).